# Javascript RegEx inside apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

RegEx help needed.

Target string is `<div class="myclassname"></div>`

When trying to capture all words **inside** apostrophes using the following :
`/"(.*?)"/`

The match is ok, but it is **containing the apostrophes** itself.

I would like to capture whatever is inside **WITHOUT** the apostrophes...

Please note that I am aware of the fact that in javascript I would get the 2nd match like `a.match(string)[1]` - and other code solutions...

I am looking for a **regex only solution**

Comment: With no lookbehinds support that is just a pipe dream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this snippet,

```js
a = '<div class="myclassname"></div>'
reg_a = a.match(/[^="]+(?=")/)
console.log(reg_a[0])
console.log(reg_a)
```

Comment: this will match any string ending in quote, not even if there is no opening quote

Comment: what about others? there is only one

Answer (score 0):

```
/(.*?=\")([^"]+?)(">[^"]*)/
```

See result in $2